# Обработчик клавиатуры java, как обработать нажатие клавиши в консоли?

Tags: java, клавиатура, консоль

Добрый всем вечер! Передо мной встал такой вопрос, можно ли в обычном консольном приложении, написанном на java, обработать нажатие клавиши с клавиатуры? Например, сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "UP" или "DOWN" какая-нибудь переменная увеличивалась или уменьшалась на единицу! Это как пример?! Может кто уже сталкивался с подобным, подскажите, как это реализуется?

Comment: Клавиши UP/DOWN и т.п. имеют свой код.. не понмю уже тончо, проверьте экспериментально.

Comment: Их код определить не сложно! Сложность в другом, с чем именно этот код сравнивать, то есть как можно "отловить" нажатие клавиши на клавиатуре?

Comment: Вам же ответили: читать стандартный ввод через System.in. Никакого другого способа просто нет.

Comment: При нажатии и UP и DOWN в консоли Windows XP у меня читается *один из ранее вводимых символов*, а в Eclipse **ничего не читается**.

Коды от стрелок и функциональных клавиш до System.in.read () не доходят.

Собственно в программе на Си то же самое. Обработчик винды ничего не шлет в поток ввода для этих клавиш.

Если читать напрямую (getch()), то UP и DOWN дают пары байт "pI" и "pQ". Как отличить их от "клавиатурных" p и I не знаю.

Comment: С эклипсом тут ясно, что стрелки просто двигают курсор в логе вывода. С консолью XP тоже всё ясно. Если всё как вы говорите, то значит нормального способа не существует.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Средствами Java реализовать консольный отлов нажатия функциональных клавиш невозможно. Отловить удастся только клавиши, добавляющие в консоль некоторый символ.

Варианты решения:

1. Написать свое AWT/Swing или даже SWT - приложение, имитирующее консоль, но вместо нее содержащее текстовое поле, к которому уже навесить нужные слушатели.
2. Выбрать клавишу (или сочетание клавиш), вводящую в консоль некоторый символ (например, "+" и "-" для переключения переменной). И попробовать убирать этот символ из консоли, дописывать в нее желаемые результаты и т.д (в том, что удастся такое реализовать - сомневаюсь).

В обоих случаях нужно не забыть позаботиться о кроссплатформенности приложения, иначе использовать Java для подобных целей вообще не стоит.

Answer (score 4):

Маловероятно, что это можно сделать средствами Java. Скорее всего придется писать нативный код под нужную платформу и цеплять его через JNI. Можно попробовать работать с [curses](http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2008/01/java-native-interface-jni-notebook.html) (ncurses).

Comment: "Можно попробовать работать с curses (ncurses)."

Тогда уж лучше (для винды) с Windows API.

Answer (score 3):

```
    char ch ;
    int code ;
    while ( -1 != (code = System.in.read ()) )
    {
        ch = (char) code ;
        System.out.println ( "you pressed: '" + ch + "'\n" ) ;

        // выйти когда нажато 'q'
        if ( 'q' == ch )
        {
            System.exit ( 0 ) ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно за ответ, но это не совсем то, что нужно... Как обработать конкретный символ, введенный с клавиатуры я представляю, а вот как обработать нажатие таких клавиш, как "UP","DOWN","LEFT","RIGHT" и тому подобное?! Да еще и в режиме реального нажатия, так сказать) То есть нажал на "UP" и она выводит сообщение какое-нибудь например... Может быть в консоли это не реализуется,только в Swing, я не знаю?! Поэтому и спрашиваю!

Comment: google.com: 'ascii character map'

Comment: @jmu, поясните, какое отношение 'ascii character map' имеет к чтению  **функциональных клавиш** через стандартный поток ввода ? 

Я именно так понимаю смысл данного вопроса.

Comment: все эти клавиши считываются одинаково. другое дело что система --> IDE/консоль непозволяет вам считывать их. а если еще точнее то они обрабатываются еще до того как записываются в входной поток данных java. они ведь не просто так называются функциональными клавишами не так ли?:) 

т.е. ваша программа может теоретически их обработать, но то что вы получаете в System.in это то, что пропускает вам система - программа (иде, напр эклипс) или консоль. 

если у вас есть "очень" острая необходимость см. ответ @Петрович

Comment: Насчет native code (см. ответ @Петрович) похоже. 

Я поискал ответы на тему ввода без ожидания <Enter> и ничего обнадеживающего не нашел.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html - вот тут, в принципе, все есть.

```
public class KeyEventDemo ...  implements KeyListener ... {
...
    /** Handle the key-pressed event*/
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e == KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP ) {
            //Insert your code here
        } else if (e == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_LEFT) {
            //Insert your code here
        } else if (e == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT) {
            //Insert your code here
        }
    }
...
}
```

На работоспособность не проверял

Comment: @Антон Феоктистов А следовало бы проверить... И следовало бы узнать зачем нужен swing для начала.

Comment: KeyListener, это то же самое, о чем и я подумал в первую очередь! =) Но тогда столкнулся с такой проблемой, как вызывать этот самый метод keyPressed?! Какой аргумент ему нужно передать? Из чего его вытащить, если обычный read() нажатие этих клавиш  не распознает?

Comment: Может в этом интерфейсе есть какой-то метод для "считывания" действий клавиатуры?

Comment: zavtramen, ваше замечание по поводу того, что этот класс только для Swing используется?! Я правильно понял?

Comment: @zavtramen лучше бы тогда ответ написали вместо язвительства)

Comment: Для swing и AWT. И события эти возникают из Event Queue. Нет окна - нет событий.

Comment: да, я был не прав

Answer (score 1):

```
public class AirBallon {
private static int x_location=350;
static JFrame finalMenu=new JFrame();
public static void start1(){
finalMenu.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {

           switch (evt.getKeyCode() ) {
             case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                if(x_location>700)
                 break;
                   right(x_location);

                   x_location++;
                   System.out.println(x_location);
                   break;
               case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                   if(x_location<0)
                       break;
                   right(x_location) ;
                   x_location--;

                   break;
               case KeyEvent.VK_UP:

                     up();

                   break;

               default:
               System.out.println("");
           break;}

 private static void right(int k) {

            labe2.setBounds(k, 450, 100, 150);}

}
```