# Отслеживание нажатия клавиш java

Tags: java

Есть ли в Java метод, который просто возвращает нажатую в данный момент клавишу?
Как например метод `getch()` из msvcrt в python, там все вообще легко:

```
from msvcrt import getch, kbhit
while 1:
    if kbhit():
        print(getch())
```

Хочу сделать примерно тоже в Java.

Если что, хочу сделать что-то типа змейки в консольном окне

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Отсюда](http://www.cyberforum.ru/java-gui/thread286729.html):

1) Определение по коду источник события:

```
addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                formKeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });
```

2) Проверяем нажатую клавишу:

```
private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    switch (evt.getKeyCode()) {

        case KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE:
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER: //Нажата клавиша Enter
            break;

        default:
    }
}
```

Вообще, на [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/59025/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-java-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8) уже отвечали.

By [Selden](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5700/selden):

> Средствами Java реализовать консольный отлов нажатия функциональных
>   клавиш невозможно. Отловить удастся только клавиши, добавляющие в
>   консоль некоторый символ.
>
> Варианты решения:
>
> - Написать свое AWT/Swing или даже SWT - приложение, имитирующее
>     консоль, но вместо нее содержащее текстовое поле, к которому уже
>     навесить нужные слушатели.
> - Выбрать клавишу (или сочетание клавиш), вводящую в консоль некоторый
>     символ (например, "+" и "-" для переключения переменной). И
>     попробовать убирать этот символ из консоли, дописывать в нее желаемые
>     результаты и т.д (в том, что удастся такое реализовать - сомневаюсь).
>
> В обоих случаях нужно не забыть позаботиться о кроссплатформенности
>   приложения, иначе использовать Java для подобных целей вообще не
>   стоит.

А вообще, могли бы погуглить. Есть куча хороших статей про игры на Java.

Например, [WikiBooks](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java/%D0%98%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0) или [TProger](https://tproger.ru/articles/java-15-mins-snake/).