# отловить нажатие ESCAPE

Tags: java, консоль

Подскажите пожалуйста, делаю простое консольное приложение, где создается поток который выполняет какое то действие, во время выполнения хочу по нажатию клавиши 'Escape' прекращать выполнение программы. В swing это можно сделать с помощью KeyListener. Можно ли с консоли выполнить данное действие?

Comment: `System.in.read ()` дальше приводим к `(char)` и сравниваем с чем надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил данный вопрос с помощью сторонней библиотеки JNativeHook. Может кому то поможет. Так же можно решать с помощью создания паралельных потоков. Оставленный в комментарии ответ по поводу System.in.read() не совсем подходил в данной ситуации, так как он ожидает выполнения действия, и только после этого продолжает выполнение. Идея была, при паралельном выполнении программы, в случае нажатии клавиш клавиатуры, выполнялись определенные действия(хотя может я просто не правильно юзал System.in.read(), а у Вас все получится!!:).

Answer (score -1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

```
public class AirBallon {
private static int x_location=350;
static JFrame finalMenu=new JFrame();
public static void start1(){
finalMenu.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {

           switch (evt.getKeyCode() ) {
             case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                if(x_location>700)
                 break;
                   right(x_location);

                   x_location++;
                   System.out.println(x_location);
                   break;
               case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                   if(x_location<0)
                       break;
                   right(x_location) ;
                   x_location--;

                   break;
               case KeyEvent.VK_UP:

                     up();

                   break;

               default:
               System.out.println("");
           break;}

 private static void right(int k) {

            labe2.setBounds(k, 450, 100, 150);}

}
```

С java не знаком, пример взял от [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/59025/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-java-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8?rq=1)

Comment: Вы читали вопрос? Причем тут события, как вы ими будете оперировать в консольном приложении. Я написал, что нужно сделать в комменте.

Comment: Создать отдельный поток который и будет отслеживать события, так нельзя?
Или для вас это проблема?